# Meaning of the phrase "theatre of pain"

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin

This [BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/50369640) says

> Anfield has also been nothing but a **theatre of pain** for Guardiola
>   since he arrived in England

What is the origin of this phrase? It sounds quite gruesome. I'm aware of phrases like "security theatre" or "political theatre" - which are metaphors for actual theatre - but this sounds like a reference to something specific (besides a [Mötley Crüe album](http://www.westwoodvalley.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Motley-Crue-Theatre-Of-Pain.jpg)).

Comment: It is not "a phrase". It is just writing. Why do people so often not understand that *one can write creatively without using all the usual clichés*? That said, it does echo off of things like "theater of the absurd" or "theater of cruelty" (from the French, théâtre de la cruauté)

Comment: A Google Ngram search turns up an 1828 example of 'theatre of pain [and tribulation]' in [Portugal Or, who is the Lawful Successor to the Throne Being an Enquiry ...
By Paulo Midosi](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=64cDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA152&dq=%22theatre+of+pain%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkyqOkxOLlAhW2SRUIHTWjCp8Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22theatre%20of%20pain%22&f=false).

Comment: @Lambie you've answered your own question. I'm not disputing that people can create fresh phrases, but they're usually anchored in some common mental image or historical reference. Both "theatre of cruelty" and the "theatre of the absurd" have clear origins in concepts in dramatic criticism (respectively originating in Artaud and Brecht) - that is to say, there is a literal _theatrical referent_!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks for the tip. I suppose in a sense one can understand "theatre" loosely as just a venue where strong emotion is publicly observed. I found a handful of results for "theatre of wonder", "theatre of love", "theatre of awe", etc.

Comment: *It sounds quite gruesome.*  Yes, I think that's the point, to poor Mr Guardiola it was a gruesome visit to Anfield.

Comment: Manchester United's Old Trafford ground has the nickname the 'Theatre of Dreams'. Though at the moment, perhaps a reawakening is what's needed.

Comment: "Manchester United's Old Trafford ground has the nickname the 'Theatre of Dreams'" - Often very wet in Manchester. Is that the reason?